# How to set Date from and To with month beginning and end dates?

Tags: .net, vb.net, date

I have a form load function and In the form I have two date fields _Datefrom and _Dateto. I want to set these fields as the beginning and end date of the month. So for example if the current month is February, I want to set it as

```
_DateFrom = 2/1/2016
```

and

```
_Dateto = 2/29/2016
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it

```
Dim dateFrom = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1)
Dim dateTo = datefrom.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have one more question: I am relating two fields Duedate and completed date to the Date from and to fields. On this, the Duedate is set as fuzzy date on the backend and I am not sure about how to convert it to date field.